# Retrieve mysql records using datetime a week before the event and then all events already expired this year

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, prepared-statement

I have an exhibitions page on my website that I want to list all events coming up a week before they start and also to keep them displayed until the end of the current year after the event.
We used to have them displayed all year but my employer now wants to only display them a week before the event and for the events to stay listed until the start of the new year.

I have the following code which works for extracting records from a week before the event. However, the part I'm struggling with is keeping each of the records from this year displayed for the remainder of the year.

```
if ($exhstmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT eventname, startdate, enddate, location, location_url 
                                 FROM exhibitions 
                                 WHERE DATE(startdate) = date_sub(date(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) 
                                 ORDER BY startdate ASC")){
```

I did try to have the current year stated in the database and extract from that but it doesn't work with the above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: I take it you'll only be accepting one of the answers when the year is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using DATE_ADD to add a week to NOW and also selecting where the date of your event is less than or equal to this newly genertaed date+1 week

```
SELECT eventname, startdate, enddate, location, location_url 
FROM exhibitions 
WHERE YEAR(startdate) = YEAR(NOW())
  AND DATE(startdate) <= DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
ORDER BY startdate ASC
```

Comment: thanks Riggs. I used your suggestion.Apologies for the slow acceptance, I had finished work for the day and left the question to be answered overnight ready for when I got back to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query would be clearer using `date_add()` rather than `date_sub()`.  You need to check for the current year as well:

```
SELECT eventname, startdate, enddate, location, location_url
FROM exhibitions
WHERE DATE(startdate) <= date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) OR
      (YEAR(startdate) = YEAR(CURDATE() AND startdate <= CURDATE())
ORDER BY startdate ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried BETWEEN? Give this a shot.

WHERE DATE(startdate) BETWEEN date_sub(date(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND CONCAT(YEAR(curdate()),'-12-31')